# The correct use of the verb "to afford"

Tags: vocabulary

I've just found these two examples about the use of the verb *to afford*:

> I would like to be able **to afford** a new car next year, so I won't be going away for the holidays.
>
> With the salary I earn, I can't imagine ever being able **to afford to buy** my own house.

In the first sentence, the writter used only the verb *to afford*, but in the second one, he uses *to afford to buy*.

Is it relevant for the meaning of the second sentence to add the verb *to buy*? Would he convey the same message using only *to afford*?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is simply that the words "to buy" have been elided in the first sentence, as they could well be in the second. The only point in including them is for clarification purposes, that I didn't mean "Whilst I could afford the purchase cost, I could not afford to run my own house/car"

Comment: There's a subtle difference (whether intentional or not) between being able to afford a thing: "a car" -- and being able to afford to perform an action: "to buy". The first ***directly*** involves money / finances. The other usage may involve things other than finances, such as time, emotional or physical stresses, and so on. That's because **to buy** is a process or activity which often enough includes important aspects besides simply writing a check.

Comment: Being able to afford a thing (like a car), requires only money. But being able to afford **to buy** a thing (like a house or car or dress, etc.), can involve many factors besides money alone. The latter usage is figurative rather than literal. For example, "I can't afford to lose you" is most often a declaration of an emotional state, rather than a literal statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *to buy* could be left out of the second sentence without much changing its meaning.

The word *afford* means (depending a little on context) *spare the resources for* something; those resources needn’t be, though usually are, financial, but can also refer to a cost in stamina, or reputation. There is sometimes a degree of volition involved, in which case it’s a synonym for *[brook](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/brook)* (sense 2, *tolerate*).

In general think of *can afford* as meaning *can stand the cost of*, in whatever sense of *cost*.